# For loop output in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to understand the for loop better. I have the following variables:

x = 1

y = 10

I want to increment x and double it ten times with a for loop to have the following output: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

This is what I have, but it is not quite doing the trick:

```
int x = 1;

int y = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
    x *= 2;

}

printf("%d\n", x);
```

Do I need another variable to do this?

Comment: Put the output inside the loop

Comment: Why did you accept an answer to this question the *first* time you posted it if it didn't answer the question?

Comment: As @Ed asked, do you want powers of two or do you want to increment x and double it ten times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to display a running count then you should place `printf` inside the for-loop, so it gets executed with each iteration.

> Do I need another variable to do this?

No. You could actually remove a variable - `y`. It is unneeded and you can specify 10 directly in the loop's conditional:

```
int i = 0;
int x = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    x *= 2;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks fine to me. If you want it to print at each iteration, you need to move the `printf` into the loop.

Also, your code will only work in C99 or with GCC's default extensions since you have `int i` inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to increment x and double it ten times with a for loop to have the following output: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

Your example contradicts your requirement. Incrementing an integer and doubling it would look produce 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14...n.  They are simply multiples of two.  Your example produces *powers* of two, i.e.,

```
int x;
for( x = 0; x < 10; ++x )
{
    printf("%d\n", pow(2, x) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
    x *= 2;
   printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you want the printf statement inside the for loop... between the { and the }.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 1;
int y = 10;
int i = 0;

int main() {
  for(i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    x *= 2;
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer contradict with your source code,if you want to print 1,2,4,8,16,... you will get first element 2, because you are multiplying every iteration 2 times than its value, you do not need to use extra variable,moreover you can remove y,put directly 10 and use printf statement inside {}.hope it will help

Comment: FYI leaving an answer on a question that was asked and answered over two years ago probably isn't going to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you know that you have to increment it for only 10 times. Then why to use extra variable ? use this....

```
for(x = 1; x<=1024; x*=2)
    {
    printf("%d ",x);
    }
```